# Magento multiCall with android ksoap2

Tags: android, magento, ksoap2

I'm having problems calling multiCall Magento method with android kSoap2 library. Does anyone have any examples?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope that link may help you.

[Whats correct way to use multicall method of magento SOAP API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260570/whats-correct-way-to-use-multicall-method-of-magento-soap-api)

https://github.com/lognllc/LogNMagento

Comment: thanks, but I solved it with xmlrpc protocol using android-xmlrpc library